# Displaying two views simultaneously

Tags: django, django-views

I am stuck trying to display two different views on the same page simultaneously.  If I comment out the `user_creation` url, then the `userlist` view will display.  Otherwise, if both urls are uncommented, the url listed first will indicate which view will be visible (in this case, `user_creation`).

How can I display both views on the same page simultaneously?

(PS: I'm a Django beginner)

**EDIT:** Since I cannot have two views, I will describe my objective. I am trying to display:

1. A form where a user can input information to create a user, and
2. A list of the users already created.  As new users are created using form input, the list of users (displayed somewhere, don't really care where or how its visually laid out) will update to show all users, including the newly created user.

Again, the code that I displayed works for each purpose individually, but I cannot show both sections/modules at the same time.

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin

admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
  url(r'^$', 'users.views.user_creation', name='user_creation'),  
  url(r'^$', 'users.views.userlist', name='userlist'),
  url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response, RequestContext
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from users.models import User
from users.forms import UserForm

def user_creation(request):
  form = UserForm(request.POST or None)

  if form.is_valid():
    save_it = form.save(commit=False)
    save_it.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/')

  return render_to_response("users/base.html",
                            locals(),
                            context_instance=RequestContext(request))

def userlist(request):
  return render_to_response("users/userlist.html",
                           {'users': User.objects.all()})
```

**base.html**

```
<html>
  <body>
    <h1>User Management</h1><br>

    <form method='POST' action=''> {% csrf_token %}
      {{ form.as_p }}
      <input type='submit' value="Create">
    </form>

    <!--userlist.html block-->
    {% block userlist_block %}
    {% endblock %}

  </body>
</html>
```

**userlist.html**

```
{% extends "users/base.html" %}

{% block userlist_block %}
  {% for user in users %}
    {{ user.name_first }} {{ ' ' }}
    {{ user.name_last }} {{ '; ' }}
    {{ user.email_1 }}</li>
  {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: You can't display two views at the same time.

Comment: You can not do that. But you can write a view and decide which template you want to render with which context. Tell us what you want to do exactly?

Comment: @FallenAngel - See edits to OP.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to achieve this using a type of template tag called an inclusion tag. [Read about them here.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#inclusion-tags)